# Compatibility of ANSI codes in python?

Tags: python

I use ANSI colour codes in my python programs ( like this `print("\u001b[36;1mExample!")` ) and once I sent one of my programs to my friend but for them it printed "\u001b[36;1mExample!" instead of changing the colour of the text and printing "Example!" like it does for me on WINDOWS10 and as it should do.

So I was curious which OS's will actually change the colour as it should and which will just print the colour code? Or does it depend on something other than OS?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the terminal the program is run in. Not all terminals support ANSI escape codes. System terminals seem to have a higher chance of supporting it. Terminals in IDEs seem to rarely support them.

Comment: In Windows, Microsoft supported it in the console in 3.1 up to 95, removed support In Vista, made it optionally available in 7, and put support back in an update to 10. Not everyone has always agreed with your assessment *as it should do*.